# Where do I find "libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit)" for Amazon Linux?

Tags: yum, gtk, amazon-linux

I'm using Amazon Linux.  When I run "sudo yum install" it eventually errors out with the following

```
[myuser@mydomain ~]$ sudo yum update
[sudo] password for myuser:
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * CentOS-base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * CentOS-extras: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
 * CentOS-updates: mirrors.centos.webair.com
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirrors.centos.webair.com
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                                                     | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                                                                  | 2.3 kB     00:00
6590 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package GConf2.x86_64 0:2.28.0-6.el6 will be updated
---> Package GConf2.x86_64 0:2.28.0-7.el6 will be an update
---> Package ORBit2.x86_64 0:2.14.17-5.el6 will be updated
...
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:60.0.3112.78-1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-60.0.3112.78-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-60.0.3112.78-1.x86_64
---> Package texlive-currfile.noarch 2:svn29012.0.7b-27.21.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:60.0.3112.78-1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-60.0.3112.78-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-60.0.3112.78-1.x86_64
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:4.4.5-15.26.amzn1 will be erased
---> Package kernel-devel.x86_64 0:4.4.5-15.26.amzn1 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-60.0.3112.78-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-60.0.3112.78-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
2000:jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2000:jdk-1.6.0_35-fcs.x86_64
2000:jdk-1.6.0_65-fcs.x86_64 is a duplicate with 2000:jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64
```

Where do I find this mysterious "libgtk-3.so.0" library?  When I Google it, I see an RPM site, but Amazon Linux isn't an RPM-based system (unless I'm reading something wrong).  How do I find and install this mystery library?

**Edit:** Error in response to answer given

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ sudo yum search libgtk
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * CentOS-base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * CentOS-extras: centos.vwtonline.net
 * CentOS-updates: mirrors.centos.webair.com
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirrors.centos.webair.com
6590 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
============================================================================================= Matched: libgtk ==============================================================================================
gtkhtml2.i686 : An HTML widget for GTK+ 2.0
gtkhtml2.x86_64 : An HTML widget for GTK+ 2.0
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ sudo yum -y install gtkhtml2.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * CentOS-base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * CentOS-extras: centos.vwtonline.net
 * CentOS-updates: mirrors.centos.webair.com
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirrors.centos.webair.com
6590 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ sudo yum -y install gtkhtml2.i686
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * CentOS-base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * CentOS-extras: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
 * CentOS-updates: mirrors.centos.webair.com
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirrors.centos.webair.com
6590 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gtkhtml2.i686 0:2.11.1-7.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.0) for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.4.30) for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libxml2.so.2 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libpango-1.0.so.0 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgailutil.so.18 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreetype.so.6 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfontconfig.so.1 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcairo.so.2 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libatk-1.0.so.0 for package: gtkhtml2-2.11.1-7.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package atk.i686 0:1.30.0-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package cairo.i686 0:1.12.14-6.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpixman-1.so.0 for package: cairo-1.12.14-6.8.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXext.so.6 for package: cairo-1.12.14-6.8.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6 for package: cairo-1.12.14-6.8.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb-render.so.0 for package: cairo-1.12.14-6.8.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXrender.so.1 for package: cairo-1.12.14-6.8.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb-shm.so.0 for package: cairo-1.12.14-6.8.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libpng12.so.0(PNG12_0) for package: cairo-1.12.14-6.8.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libpng12.so.0 for package: cairo-1.12.14-6.8.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libGL.so.1 for package: cairo-1.12.14-6.8.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb.so.1 for package: cairo-1.12.14-6.8.amzn1.i686
---> Package fontconfig.i686 0:2.8.0-5.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.1 for package: fontconfig-2.8.0-5.8.amzn1.i686
---> Package freetype.i686 0:2.3.11-15.14.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package gdk-pixbuf2.i686 0:2.24.1-6.el6_7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtiff.so.3 for package: gdk-pixbuf2-2.24.1-6.el6_7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2) for package: gdk-pixbuf2-2.24.1-6.el6_7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62 for package: gdk-pixbuf2-2.24.1-6.el6_7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libjasper.so.1 for package: gdk-pixbuf2-2.24.1-6.el6_7.i686
---> Package gtk2.x86_64 0:2.24.23-8.el6 will be updated
---> Package gtk2.i686 0:2.24.23-9.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcups.so.2 for package: gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXrandr.so.2 for package: gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXinerama.so.1 for package: gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXi.so.6 for package: gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXfixes.so.3 for package: gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXdamage.so.1 for package: gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXcursor.so.1 for package: gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXcomposite.so.1 for package: gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.i686
---> Package gtk2.x86_64 0:2.24.23-9.el6 will be an update
---> Package libxml2.i686 0:2.9.1-6.3.49.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: liblzma.so.5 for package: libxml2-2.9.1-6.3.49.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0) for package: libxml2-2.9.1-6.3.49.amzn1.i686
---> Package pango.i686 0:1.28.1-10.11.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libthai.so.0(LIBTHAI_0.1) for package: pango-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXft.so.2 for package: pango-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libthai.so.0 for package: pango-1.28.1-10.11.amzn1.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-libtiff3.i686 0:3.9.4-21.15.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) for package: compat-libtiff3-3.9.4-21.15.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: compat-libtiff3-3.9.4-21.15.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: compat-libtiff3-3.9.4-21.15.amzn1.i686
---> Package cups-libs.i686 1:1.4.2-67.21.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26 for package: 1:cups-libs-1.4.2-67.21.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4) for package: 1:cups-libs-1.4.2-67.21.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libavahi-client.so.3 for package: 1:cups-libs-1.4.2-67.21.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libavahi-common.so.3 for package: 1:cups-libs-1.4.2-67.21.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libtiff.so.5(LIBTIFF_4.0) for package: 1:cups-libs-1.4.2-67.21.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libtiff.so.5 for package: 1:cups-libs-1.4.2-67.21.amzn1.i686
---> Package expat.x86_64 0:2.1.0-8.18.amzn1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: expat = 2.1.0-8.18.amzn1 for package: expat-devel-2.1.0-8.18.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package expat.i686 0:2.1.0-10.21.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package expat.x86_64 0:2.1.0-10.21.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package jasper-libs.x86_64 0:1.900.1-16.9.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package jasper-libs.i686 0:1.900.1-21.9.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package jasper-libs.x86_64 0:1.900.1-21.9.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libX11.i686 0:1.6.0-2.2.12.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXcomposite.i686 0:0.4.3-4.6.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXcursor.i686 0:1.1.14-2.1.9.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXdamage.i686 0:1.1.3-4.7.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXext.i686 0:1.3.2-2.1.10.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXfixes.i686 0:5.0.1-2.1.8.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXft.i686 0:2.3.1-2.7.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXi.i686 0:1.7.2-2.2.9.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXinerama.i686 0:1.1.2-2.7.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXrandr.i686 0:1.4.1-2.1.8.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXrender.i686 0:0.9.8-2.1.9.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libjpeg-turbo.i686 0:1.2.90-5.14.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libpng.i686 2:1.2.49-2.14.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libthai.i686 0:0.1.12-3.5.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libxcb.x86_64 0:1.8.1-1.18.amzn1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb = 1.8.1-1.18.amzn1 for package: libxcb-devel-1.8.1-1.18.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb-sync.so.0()(64bit) for package: libxcb-devel-1.8.1-1.18.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package libxcb.i686 0:1.11-2.21.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6 for package: libxcb-1.11-2.21.amzn1.i686
---> Package libxcb.x86_64 0:1.11-2.21.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package mesa-libGL.x86_64 0:10.1.2-2.32.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mesa-libGL.i686 0:10.1.2-2.35.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mesa-dri-drivers(x86-32) = 10.1.2-2.35.amzn1 for package: mesa-libGL-10.1.2-2.35.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXxf86vm.so.1 for package: mesa-libGL-10.1.2-2.35.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libglapi.so.0 for package: mesa-libGL-10.1.2-2.35.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libdrm.so.2 for package: mesa-libGL-10.1.2-2.35.amzn1.i686
---> Package mesa-libGL.x86_64 0:10.1.2-2.35.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package pixman.i686 0:0.32.4-4.11.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package xz-libs.i686 0:5.1.2-12alpha.12.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package avahi-libs.i686 0:0.6.25-12.17.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libdbus-1.so.3 for package: avahi-libs-0.6.25-12.17.amzn1.i686
---> Package expat-devel.x86_64 0:2.1.0-8.18.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package expat-devel.x86_64 0:2.1.0-10.21.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package gnutls.x86_64 0:2.8.5-19.15.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package gnutls.i686 0:2.12.23-21.18.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtasn1.so.3(LIBTASN1_0_3) for package: gnutls-2.12.23-21.18.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libtasn1.so.3 for package: gnutls-2.12.23-21.18.amzn1.i686
---> Package gnutls.x86_64 0:2.12.23-21.18.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libXau.i686 0:1.0.6-4.9.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXxf86vm.i686 0:1.1.3-2.1.9.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libdrm.i686 0:2.4.52-4.12.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpciaccess.so.0 for package: libdrm-2.4.52-4.12.amzn1.i686
---> Package libstdc++48.i686 0:4.8.3-9.111.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libtiff.x86_64 0:4.0.3-25.27.amzn1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libtiff(x86-64) = 4.0.3-25.27.amzn1 for package: libtiff-devel-4.0.3-25.27.amzn1.x86_64
---> Package libtiff.i686 0:4.0.3-27.29.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libjbig.so.2.0 for package: libtiff-4.0.3-27.29.amzn1.i686
---> Package libtiff.x86_64 0:4.0.3-27.29.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package libxcb-devel.x86_64 0:1.8.1-1.18.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libxcb-devel.x86_64 0:1.11-2.21.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package mesa-dri-drivers.x86_64 0:10.1.2-2.32.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mesa-dri-drivers.i686 0:10.1.2-2.35.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mesa-dri-filesystem(x86-32) for package: mesa-dri-drivers-10.1.2-2.35.amzn1.i686
---> Package mesa-dri-drivers.x86_64 0:10.1.2-2.35.amzn1 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dbus-libs.i686 1:1.6.12-14.28.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package jbigkit-libs.i686 0:2.0-11.4.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libpciaccess.i686 0:0.13.1-4.1.11.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libtasn1.i686 0:2.3-6.6.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libtiff-devel.x86_64 0:4.0.3-25.27.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package libtiff-devel.x86_64 0:4.0.3-27.29.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package mesa-dri-filesystem.x86_64 0:10.1.2-2.32.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mesa-dri-filesystem.i686 0:10.1.2-2.35.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package mesa-dri-filesystem.x86_64 0:10.1.2-2.35.amzn1 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for gdk-pixbuf2 which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of gdk-pixbuf2 of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude gdk-pixbuf2.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of gdk-pixbuf2 installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of gdk-pixbuf2 installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: gdk-pixbuf2-2.24.1-6.el6_7.i686 != gdk-pixbuf2-2.28.2-4.1.ll1.x86_64
Error: Protected multilib versions: atk-1.30.0-1.el6.i686 != atk-2.8.0-4.1.ll1.x86_64
```

Comment: A `sudo yum whatprovides '*/libgtk-3*'` shows that RPM as existing in the EPEL repository on my Centos 7 test system. (yum wraps rpm so your system is indeed rpm-based)

Comment: So you're saying I shoudl run a yum install command or an rpm install command?

Answer (score 0):

this finds the package name

```
sudo yum search libgtk
```

Install that package

```
sudo yum -y install <package name>
```

Comment: No dice.  Running your suggestion dies with the error, "Error: Protected multilib versions: atk-1.30.0-1.el6.i686 != atk-2.8.0-4.1.ll1.x86_64".  I included the complete output as an edit to m yquestion.